# Are lust/anger considered Rajasic or Tamasic?

Tags: gunas, rajasic, tamasic

I used to think anger is Rajasic and lust is Tamasic.But after reading much about Gunas, at many places lust is shown as Rajasic while anger is shown as Tamasic. I thought Tamas represents laziness while Rajas represents activity and passion . So Which one is true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the following verse of Manu Smriti lust is Rajasik.

> आरम्भरुचिताऽधैर्यमसत्कार्यपरिग्रहः ।
>  विषयोपसेवा चाजस्रं राजसं
> गुणलक्षणम् ॥ ३२ ॥
>
> ārambharucitā'dhairyamasatkāryaparigrahaḥ |
>  viṣayopasevā cājasraṃ
> rājasaṃ guṇalakṣaṇam || 32 ||
>
> Proneness to undertake work, impatience, commission of improper acts,
> constant addiction to sensual objects are the characteristics of the
> quality of ‘Rajas.’—(32)
>
> [Manu Smriti 12.32](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202212.html)

And the traits of Tamasika nature are mentioned in the very [next verse](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202213.html):

> लोभः स्वप्नोऽधृतिः क्रौर्यं नास्तिक्यं भिन्नवृत्तिता ।
>  याचिष्णुता
> प्रमादश्च तामसं गुणलक्षणम् ॥ ३३ ॥
>
> lobhaḥ svapno'dhṛtiḥ krauryaṃ nāstikyaṃ bhinnavṛttitā |
>  yāciṣṇutā
> pramādaśca tāmasaṃ guṇalakṣaṇam || 33 ||
>
> Avarice, drowsiness, irresolution, cruelty, disbelief, bad character,
> habit of begging, and inattentiveness are the characteristics of the
> quality of ‘Tamas.’—(33)

However, according to 12.38, constant craving of sensual pleasures is mentioned to be Tamasik in nature.

> 12.38. **The craving after sensual pleasures is declared to be the mark of Darkness**, (the pursuit of) wealth (the mark) of Activity,
> (the desire to gain) spiritual merit the mark of Goodness; each later)
> named quality is) better than the preceding one.

So, I think lust can be Tamasik as well as Rajasik depending on circumstances. Regarding anger, nothing is mentioned explicitly. But if we connect it to cruelty anger becomes Tamasik in nature by virtue of 12.33.

Devi Bhagavatam also mentions anger as a Tamasik trait. See the following verses:

> 7-8. The intelligent should understand that Rajas has certainly arisen
> in him, when his mind is filled with hatred, enmity, quarrelsome
> feeling, pride, stupification, uneasiness, sleeplessness, want of
> faith, egoism, vanity and arrogance. 9-11. The quality Tamas is of
> black colour. From Tamas arises laziness, ignorance, sleep, poverty,
> fear, quarrels, miserliness, insincerity, anger, aberration of
> intellect, violent atheism, and finding fault with others. The wise
> should think that Tamas has overpowered him when the above qualities
> are found to possess him. When this Tamas quality is attended with the
> Tâmasî faith, then it becomes the source of pain to others.
> 12. The well wishers should manifest in themselves the Sattva qualities, control the Râjasic qualities, and destroy the Tâmasic
> qualities
>
> *(from Book 3; Chapter 8)*

Adding some further references from other scriptures:

> Non-violence, truth, non-theft, continence and non-possession, absence
> of anger, service to elders, cleanliness, contentment and honesty,
> non-conceit, candour, faith and non-injury – are the qualities
> (effects) of Sattva. I am the doer, enjoyer, speaker, am conceited –
> these are of Rajas. Sleep, laziness, delusion, attachment, sex and
> theft – these are of Tamas. The person of Sattva is above, of Rajas is
> in the middle and of Tamas, low.
>
> (From Sariraka Upanishad linked to Krishna Yajurveda)

So, here too sexual activity is linked with Tamas but note that semen (which is white in color) is mentioned as Sattva, blood (which is red) is mentioned as Rajas in scriptures.

> But then a person may renounce, that very day on which he gets
> disillusioned with the world, whether he is one who observes not vows
> (before the stage of renunciation) or observes them, whether he has
> undergone the prescribed ablution on completing the disciplined
> studentship or not, whether he is one who has discontinued maintaining
> the ritual fire at the death of his wife (utsannagni) or is one who
> does not maintain (for other causes) the ritual fire (anagnika). Some
> (law-givers) prescribe the sacrifice called Prajapatya (of which god
> Brahma is the presiding deity, to a twice-born before he embraces
> renunciation). But (though thus said) he may not do so. He shall only
> perform the Agneyi sacrifice (whose presiding deity is Agni, the god
> of fire). For Agni is the vital breath (Prana). Thereby he does
> (strengthen) the vital breath. (Then) he shall perform the
> Traidhataviya sacrifice (whose presiding deity is the god Indra). **By
> this (sacrifice) the three vital fluids (become strong like fire),
> namely the Sattva (semen), rajas (blood) and Tamas (the dark one).**
>
> *(From Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad's Chapter 3)*

Comment: Excellent answer sir! One doubt in various Bhasyas of Gita Brahmin is equated with only Sattva, Kshtriyas with Rajas(Sattva subordinate), Vaishyas with Rajas(Tamas subordinate) and shudras with Tamas. If anger is tamas, why Kshtriyas are not considered tamasic?

Comment: Actually even in Gita sex is mentioned. I think sex for offsprings is Sattvik, lust is rajasik, and sexual deviancy(like pedophilia,necrophilia etc) are tamasic. Is that what you meant by "lust can be tamasic as well as rajasic"?

Comment: I have doubt about Vaishya's gunas but rest are correct. Either way Vaishyas are also considered to have tamas. Doesn't Kshtriyas need tamas for their anger and fighting enemies?

Comment: Without lust offspring can not be produced so all lust can not be termed as Tamasik .. Creation in general is Rajasik. @RishX

Comment: All Gunas are present in everybody in different proportions .. without Tamas one can not sleep but everybody sleeps .. so the person who is termed as Satvik also comes under the influence of Tamas while sleeping .. so it is an inter play of the 3 Gunas @RishX

Comment: i meant uncontrollable lust and constant cravings for sexual pleasure is rajasic. While sexual deviancy is tamasic.

Comment: Suppose some injustice is happening in front of us .. naturally we will be angry but can that anger be termed as Tamasik? I don't think so .. so the instructions given are generic in nature. @RishX

Comment: Yes that is possibly correct @RishX

Comment: yes I agree. But overall in many Vedantic Bhasyas claim Kshtriya rajasic, shouldn't they have tamasic majority as well?

Comment: Thanks! I think I can understand it now. It all depends on circumstances isn't it?

Comment: A Ksatriya needs to be alert and agile to protect his subjects .. if laziness (Tamas) comes in them they won't be effective in what they do .. so they will have a mix of Gunas with Raja Guna being the predominant one. @RishX

Comment: Yes circumstances and purpose @RishX

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts! I "ticked" your answer

Comment: No problem .. glad to know that the answer helped @RishX

Comment: just one more doubt if tamasic is laziness how can it also have anger aswell? Aren't these both opposites to each other?

Comment: I think lazy people can have an angry disposition too .. some people are angry by nature .. that is Tamas .. IMO anger for a Dharmic purpose is not only Tamas. Some amount of Rajas is mixed in it @RishX

Comment: underatood thanks again!